# How to insert points in Polygon in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I want to insert hospital points inside district Polygon. District is divided into 9 polygon called WARD_NO and hospitals have locations according to polygon 1,2,3,4,5..... not according to x and y co-ordinate,so how can  I do so by using .csv file format which have column HOSPITAL_NAME and WARD_NO only. I want to locate those hospitals according to WARD_NO in the respective WARD_NO

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Do you want to __map__ (display) the hospitals at points that are in the centre of the polygons? Click 'edit' and explain a bit more about what you aim to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Is placing the hospital at the centroid of the WARD_NO acceptable? If so, add the .csv to your map and join the table to your polygon layer (tutorial on that [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html)). Then create a point layer from the WARD_NO polygons (see [the top answer of this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45243/how-to-determine-the-centroid-of-polygons) on how to do this).

Comment: Also please look for similar questions and/or read the manual. This is a pretty basic GIS concept, so must be tons of examples out there.