# Finding coordinates of centroids?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, centroids

I have a few thousands of polygons, which I found the centroid for each one of them. Now I want to find the coordinates of each centroid. But for some reason the x and y columns are empty and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked the answers here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45243/how-to-determine-the-centroid-of-polygons?rq=1?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Field Calculator for your centroid layer
2. Tick 'Update existing field'
3. Select your 'x' field in the dropdown menu under this tickbox
4. Enter the expression `$x` in the expression box and click 'OK'
5. Repeat 2-4 for the y field

Answer (score 1):

QGIS now has a centroids tool builtin.

Go to Vector > Geometry tools > Centroids

[image: Vector > Geometry tools > Centroids]

Select your input polygon layer, and output file, and Run

[image: Created centroids on map]

That gives you the centroids on the map, but the coordinates may be `hidden` in the geometry column and not shown to you in the attributes table, so finally you may wish to...

Export as CSV

[image: Export to CSV]

Now viewing the attribute table gives the coordinates:

[image: Centroid coordinates as WKT in exported CSV]

Answer (score 0):

Use Point on Surface, not use Centroid (irregular polygon).

1. Create column "x" and "y" (data type decimal).
2. Use the field calculator expression:
   `x(point_on_surface($geometry)`

Optional.
In Form Editing (Qgis 3.X) you can use this expression value default when update the vector layer.