# Creating proportional circles in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, symbology, cartography, features, visualisation

[image]

I am working with the polygon features and I would like the values to be represented in terms of proportional symbols (points). Values range from 0 to 30.

I would like that: zero value = no circle; values equal to 1 = small circle; values equal to 2 = ..; values between 2-10 = ..; Over 10 = biggest circle. It is OK to use the same colours for the different dots. How do I do it in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the layer styling panel, you first select `Graduated` for your type of symbolisation and then under `Method` you select `Size` instead of `Color`.

[image]

You can then change the start and end size, how many classes there are and the color (and shape etc.) of the symbol to get exactly the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your tip but I cannot change the method. It remains on "colour". I added a screenshot.

Comment: It **should** work with 3.4 but I would upgrade to 3.10 to be sure

Comment: I am using 3.20 and I can't find that option where you set the method (either color or size). What gives?

Comment: The problem is that you have polygons. You have to create a layer with the centroids of those polygons and the same attributes. See how to do it from here and then follow the instructions above. 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45243/how-to-determine-the-centroid-of-polygons