# Calculating semi-major and semi-minor axis length of an ellipse in QGIS

Tags: qgis, length, measurements, ellipse

I have a layer that contains ellipse-shaped geometries. The layer has projected CRS and there are also rotated ellipses in the layer. I couldn't find a tool or plugin related to semi-major and semi-minor of an ellipse.

Is there a way to calculate semi-major and semi-minor axis length?

[image]

I have added the blue points and green lines just for representation.

Comment: Are their nodes arranged in a way that they would touch those lines exactly? Then you could (ab)use distances to the centroid I guess. Otherwise I'd try oriented rectangles and use the lengths of the sides.

Comment: If the vertices are in a projected spatial reference, then once you have the center, semi-major and semi-minor are min and max distance to vertices, and orientation is the angle to the semi-major vertex. If it's a geographic SR, you can still calculate, but you need to work through forward and inverse geodesic functions.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Some lines (maybe many of them) don't touch any vertices. I mean many touches directly a boundary segment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Processing Toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Oriented minimum bounding box` tool may be another solution. This tool already generates the width and height of the bounding boxes.

[image]

[image]

Half of both will give you the semi-minor/major lengths with a negligible error. Then use **Field Calculator** to calculate them using `"width"/2` and `"height"/2`.

Answer (score 7):

`Use Menu Processing / Toolbox / Minimum bounding geometry / Minimum Oriented Rectangle`. Than the values you look for correspond to half of the sited of the rectangle.

**Edit:** as described in @Kübras solution, the `Minimum Oriented Rectangle` already contains an attribute for width and height - thus the following step, desribed in the original answer, is not necessary.

To calculate the sites, convert the polygon to lines and explode the lines - this last tool will automatically create an attribute for width and height.

*Screenshot: I created the ellipse with this expression:  `make_ellipse( make_point (0,0), 22, 55, 72)` - thus 22 and 55 for semi-minor/semi-major axis, 72 for azimuth. This corresponds almost to half of the values for the width/height attributes - the ellipse is not really round an contains just the default number of 36 segments, hence the rounding error:*
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Calculate your ellipse [center point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45243/how-to-determine-the-centroid-of-polygons) if you do not already know it.  [create a Euclidean distance raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis) from that point.  Then, use zonal statistics to get the minimum and maximum  values using the ellipse and [the Zonal Statistics tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/raster_tools/zonalstatistics.html).

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without messing with Raster?